# Обновление информации в адаптере списка ListView

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Столкнулся с такой проблемой в своем приложении:

Есть JSON файл, находящийся на удаленном сервере, в свое приложение добавил класс, наследуемый от `AsyncTask`, который парсит данные с JSON и выводит с помощью `ListView` данные на экран устройства. 
В методе `onCreate` класса `MainActivity` создаю объект написанного ранее класса, тем самым выполняя поставленную задачу (спарсить данные JSON и вывести их на экран).

Так же добавил кнопку для обновления информации. В обработчике событий на эту кнопку, очищаю `setAdapter` своего `ListView` и создаю новый объект класса, который парсит данные. Предполагал, что будет просто обновление информации в списке, но оказалось, что заново спарсенные данные записываются просто в конец списка.

Подскажите, как я могу обновить необходимую информацию?

Код Adapter'a для добавления записей в ListView:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    MainActivity.this,
    itemsList, 
    R.layout.list_item, 
    new String[]{ "currentPrice", "basePrice", "route", "bidsCount"}, 
    new int[]{R.id.currentPrice, R.id.basePrice, R.id.route, R.id.bidsCount}
);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Обработчик событий для кнопки "Обновить":

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        listView.setAdapter(null);
        new GetInfo().execute();
    }
});
```

Часть класса `GetInfo`, а именно метода `doInBackground(Void... arg0)`, где происходит парсинг и добавление данных в HashMap:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject data = item.getJSONObject("data");
    JSONObject bid = item.getJSONObject("bid");
    JSONObject bidData = bid.getJSONObject("data");

    String currentPrice = bidData.getString("currentPrice");
    String basePrice = bidData.getString("basePrice");
    String bidsCount = data.getString("bidsCount");
    String route = data.getString("route");

    HashMap<String, String> itemHashMap = new HashMap<>();

    itemHashMap.put("currentPrice", getString(R.string.current_price) + " " + currentPrice);
    itemHashMap.put("basePrice", getString(R.string.base_price) + " " + basePrice);
    itemHashMap.put("route", getString(R.string.route) + " " + route);
    itemHashMap.put("bidsCount", getString(R.string.bids_count) + " " + bidsCount);

    itemsList.add(itemHashMap);
}
```

Comment: Покажите код адаптера и код метода, который очищает `ListView`.

Comment: @post_zeew, поправил

Comment: Тогда еще нужен код `GetInfo`.

Comment: @post_zeew, класс получился более 100 строк, поэтому не вижу смысла приводить код всего класса. Добавил основное, где происходит парсинг и добавление информации в HashMap

Comment: `itemsList` – это объект какого класса?

Comment: @post_zeew, это ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> В обработчике событий на эту кнопку, очищаю `setAdapter` своего `ListView`

В строке:

```
listView.setAdapter(null);
```

Вы не очищаете данные, Вы просто обнуляете адаптер. Данные как и были в `itemsList`, так они там и остаются.

Перед добавление новых данных Вам нужно очистить коллекцию `itemsList`:

```
itemsList.clear();
itemsList.add(itemHashMap);
```

А обнулять адаптер не нужно.

Comment: Большое спасибо, все заработало :) Не хватало как раз `itemsList.clear();`

Comment: а не могли бы вы объяснить, почему не стоит обнулять адаптер? Ведь так ListView пропадает на пару мгновений и у меня возникает ощущение, что информация действительно обновилась. Да, у меня появляется Toast, говорящий о том, что идет обновление, но все же...

Comment: @AndreiO. А зачем обнулять адаптер, а потом заново создавать новый? Если Вы хотите чтобы во время обновления список был скрыт, просто скрывайте `ListView` методом `listView.setVisibility(ListView.INVISIBLE);`.